# Reading photo from contact

Tags: android

Am trying to read a contact photo into an imagebutton but I encountered a security permission exception trying to do so. From the logcat, this requires granting the global_search permission(system apps only) or using the granturipermission() which I can't find a useful example explaining how to use it. 
This is my code so far:-

```
            Cursor phone = null;
            Uri result = data.getData();
            String contactId = result.getLastPathSegment();
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

            Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(contactId));
            InputStream photoIS = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, contactUri);
            try {
                if (photoIS != null) {
                    contactBtn.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(photoIS));
                    contactBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    photoIS.close();
                    selPhoto = contactUri;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
```

The security exception is thrown at this line:- `InputStream photoIS = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, contactUri);`
Have also tried the official [android solution](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html) but still throws the exception. Any way to fix this?

Comment: HAve u added the permission to acces the contact list and the external storage?

Comment: Have added the permission but still FC.